# Core data model change without adding a model version, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, core-data, model, version

I have made some changes to the model and unfortunately didn't added a new model version. So all the users who updated the app now only get a crash at the beginning.

Is there a way to fix the model in the next update so the users don't get just a crash in the beginning of the app? It must be very frustrating for all the users. Please help

Thank you

Comment: what change you made in your core data model.

Comment: The thing is I am not sure, I think I changed nullability, the crashlytics says `This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores (schema mismatch or migration failure). It cannot perform a save operation.` and users are complaining, but I think if I make a normal update, it will still be the same, they will not be able to run the app